# Cross compiling WxWidget application for Debian64 and Debian armhf

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I'm building a WxWidget application targetting both Debian 64-bits and Debian armhf (Raspberry). I'm using eclipse as IDE running in a Debian 9.4 Virtualbox.  The VB Host is Windows10.

The eclipse workspace is organized as tree projects :

1. one project set up for Debian 64-bits architecture
2. one project set up for Debian armhf architecture (using multiarch)
3. one project with common source files.

In both the 64-bits as the armhf projects, the source code is linked in from the common project.

I installed WxWidgets for 64-bits with the following command:

```
sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-dev
```

Now, the 64-bits project compiles without errors and the executable works fine under Debian64.

Next, I like to cross-compile for armhf, so

```
sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-dev:armhf
```

Now, the armhf project compiles without errors and the executable works fine on the Raspberry Pi.

However, the compilation of the 64-bit project is broken...

Apparently, the platform specific setting for WxWidgets are defined/declared in a file called

> setup.h

this file is located at

> /usr/lib/**PLATFORM**/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-3.0/wx/

where **PLATFORM** is either x86_64-linux-gnu for Debian64 or arm-linux-gnueabihf for Debian armhf.

My observation is that installing one version of the development package installs the correct setup.h, but also removes the other...

So, how do I setup WxWidgets for multi-arch compilation for both platforms?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You either need to install wxWidgets from the armhf repository or build it yourself with the cross-compiler for that architecture.

I hope that when you try to install from the different repository the installation will happen in a different directory as well. If not you should give the `apt-get` the directory where you want the script to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, this is supposed to work using `--host` option of `wx-config`, i.e. the idea is to use `wx-config --host=x86_64 --cxxflags --libs` for one platform and `wx-config --host=armhf` for the other one. However I don't know if this works with Debian packages.

If you can't make it work with them, you could build your own libraries in different build directories, say `~/build/wx/x86_64-gtk2` and `~/build/wx/armhf-gtk2`. Then you could just use `~/build/wx/$arch-gtk2/wx-config` without installing the libraries at all.